# HP slim bluetooth keyboard connection failed

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, bluetooth

I just got the Hewlett Packard Slim Bluetooth Keyboard (KT-1281) and a corresponding HP BT Mouse. While the mouse is quickly connected and works smoothly on Ubuntu 12.04, the keyboard is detected, but establishing the connection always fails. For installing I use the Bluetooth Manager in System Settings, so no terminal.

My question is, if you have experienced the same or a similar problem and maybe found a solution. Or do you know another way for installing a bluetooth device? Or do you think it would be better to send the keyboard back? Can you recommend a BT keyboard with no numpad and no Apple assignment of keys?

Thank for your help!

Comment: I have the same problem, on Ubuntu 14.04. I can connect to it from command line, or using blueman-manager, but I can't pair it to my computer; so every time the keyboard goes to sleep, or my computer has the bluetooth turned off, the connection is lost. So is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution to my problem. With the help of the bluetooth manager I could connect my rebellious keyboard. This app is really helpful and easy to use. One can easily get it from repos:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman-manager
```

The only downside is that I have to open the tool and reconnect the keyboard after every restart. It would be nice if the setting of the connection would be more stable.

Maybe you have an idea how to get this done.